# Presentation of the monoid of self-maps of a finite set

Tags: semigroups-and-monoids

Is there a common presentation of the semigroup of functions from a given (finite) set to itself?

Comment: Are you asking about the monoid of maps from a finite set to itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several well known presentations. One has to first choose your favorite presentation of the symmetric group. Then one usually adds in a rank n-1 idempotent but some people add all of them or other elements. Then one figures out the extra relations. See [page 161](https://books.google.com/books?id=LC3jxfGEcpYC&pg=PA161) of Classical Finite Semigroups by Ganyushkin and Mazorchuk. You should know the monoid of all self-maps of a set is usually called the full transformation monoid or $T_n$ when googling.

Pages 42-43 of http://research-repository.st-andrews.ac.uk/bitstream/10023/2821/3/NikolaRuskucPhDThesis.pdf give two presentations.

Comment: I found the answer on page 161 in: Olexandr Ganyushkin • Volodymyr Mazorchuk, Classical Finite Transformation Semigroups:An Introduction, Springer 2009